# Problem in sending XML with flash

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript

I want to send xml data to php page

my xml in flash is that for examle:

```
<level id="1" mark="10"><page id="12">HI..</page></level>
```

i send it,but at the URL i see this:

```
../inex.php?xml=<level id=1 mark=10><page id=12>HI..</page></level>
```

without double qout....!!!!

so i can't read this xml with simplexml_load_file() function in php

what's wrong???!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serialize and escape your xml object otherwise you won't be able to send it to php.

Check out serialization for AS3 and php.

Cheers,
Rob